# Updating components inside a custom ui:component when it is used multiple times on same page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

I am building a simple component in JSF (Mojarra 2.1.x) where I have to access parent ui components to update them, currently I'm using binding to achieve this, but it only works as long as I don't use the component more than once on the same page.

So I need a solution that would allow me to use the component multiple times on same page.

In the following code I'm updating `commandButton` with `binding="#{msButton}"` and `panel` with `binding="#{msPanel}"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:layout="http://sterz.stlrg.gv.at/jsf/layout"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="controller" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="converter" required="true" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <p:commandButton id="msButton#{cc.attrs.controller.class.getSimpleName()}" binding="#{msButton}" value="#{msg.mehr} (#{cc.attrs.controller.itemList.size()})" type="button" />
        <p:overlayPanel id="msOverlayPanel" for=":#{msButton.clientId}" hideEffect="fade" my="right top" at="right bottom">
            <p:panel id="msPanel#{cc.attrs.controller.class.getSimpleName()}" binding="#{msPanel}" styleClass="ui-panel-fit">
                <ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{cc.attrs.controller.itemList}"
                    var="item"> 
                    <p:commandButton id="removeButton"
                        actionListener="#{cc.attrs.controller.removeItem(item)}"
                        icon="ui-icon-trash" update=":#{msPanel.clientId} :#{msButton.clientId}" ajax="true"
                        process="@this" disabled="#{cc.attrs.controller.itemList.size() == 1}"/>
                    <p:selectBooleanButton id="value1" value="#{item.exclude}"
                        offLabel="und" onLabel="und nicht" style="width:80px;">
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
                    </p:selectBooleanButton>
                    <p:autoComplete converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}"
                        readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" value="#{item.from}"
                        dropdown="true"
                        completeMethod="#{cc.attrs.controller.autocomplete}" var="gp"
                        itemLabel="#{gp.displayName}" itemValue="#{gp}">
                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" />
                    </p:autoComplete>
                    <h:outputText value=" #{msg.bis} " />
                    <p:autoComplete converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}"
                        readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" value="#{item.to}" dropdown="true"
                        completeMethod="#{cc.attrs.controller.autocomplete}" var="gp"
                        itemLabel="#{gp.displayName}" itemValue="#{gp}">
                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" />
                    </p:autoComplete>
                    <br />
                </ui:repeat>
                <hr />
                <p:commandButton id="addButton" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.controller.addItem}"
                    icon="ui-icon-plus" value="#{msg.zufuegen}" update="@parent :#{msButton.clientId}"
                    ajax="true" process="@this"/>
            </p:panel>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Any help is much apprecieted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the faces component bean

```
@FacesComponent("com.xxx.MultiselectorIdComponent")
public class MultiselectorIdComponent extends UINamingContainer
{

    UIComponent msPanel;

    // getters/settter and other ui compunents    

}
```

tell the component interface what faces component bean to use

```
<cc:interface componentType="com.xxx.MultiselectorIdComponent">
```

bind the JSF component to the one in the faces component bean

```
<p:panel binding="#{cc.msPanel}"/>
```

and to access the components, for example to update the component, we use the binding

```
<p:commandButton value="My Button" update=":#{cc.msPanel.clientId}"/>
```

**ALSO:**
A good practice is to use a parent container (like `<div>`) with the following ID

```
<div id="#{cc.clientId}">
```

Hope this helps,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could target the components for update by their style class

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="msButton" ... />

<p:panel styleClass="msPanel" ... />
```

And I guess you update them from `addButton`, which would look like this

```
<p:commandButton id="addButton" update="@(.msButton, .msPanel)" ... />
```

It should have no problems working with many `cc` instances on the same page.

**UPDATE**

You can try with `update="@composite"`, which should refresh the whole custom component. Or, the cumbersome `update="@parent @parent:@parent:@parent:@child(1)"` which should target panel and button respectively. Or `update="@parent @parent:@parent:@previous"`, which should do the same. Take a look at chapter 4.3 in  [Primefaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf) for more examples and supported keywords.

Comment: css was not meant to be used that way, also that would not solve my problem of not being able to use multiple instances of same component on one page.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid and documented use of style class as a target for `update`. Anyway, check my updated answer for more suggestions.

Comment: Does not work  javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "@parent:@parent" referenced from... @composite also does not work

Comment: @lada.dvorak Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I solve similar problem by common bean "bindingBean" stored in ViewContext. BindingBean holds all binded component in internal MAP of component records. The key of hash map is an EL expression - it is factory of the component. EL is used for components creating. Components are hold in records stored in MAP in bind bean.

Example:

```
<h:panel binding="#{bindBean.get('msPanelFactory.getPanel()').component}"/>
```

Record:

```
public class BindingRecord {
    private Object component;
    private String compExpr;

    public BindingRecord(String compExpr) {
        this.compExpr = compExpr;
    }
    public Object getComponent() {
        if (component == null) {
            component = getValueExprValue("#{" + compExpr + "}");
        }
        return component;
    }
    public void setComponent(Object component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
    public Object getStoredComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

Binding bean:

```
public class BindingBean {
    private final Map<String, BindingRecord> bindingMap = new HashMap<>();
    public BindingRecord get(String key) {
        BindingRecord result = bindingMap.get(key);
        if (result == null) {
            result = new BindingRecord(key);
            bindingMap.put(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In you case you can use:

```
<h:panel binding="#{bindingBean.get('panelFactory.create()').component}"/>
```

Inside composite component you can use trick - Pass component name by composite parameter:

```
<h:panel binding="#{bindingBean.get('panelFactory.create('.concate(cc.attrs.componentName).concate(')')).component}"/>
```